# How to refactor duplicity in code that calls super

Tags: cocoa, refactoring

I have two NSResponder methods (cut, copy) and they have basically the same code except they call their own super. How to create method with parameter _CMD as selector that calls super and I won't end up with recursion?

```
- (void)copy:(id)sender
{
    [self notifyAndPerformSelector:_cmd withObject:sender];
}

- (void)cut:(id)sender
{
    [self notifyAndPerformSelector:_cmd withObject:sender];
}

- (void)notifyAndPerformSelector:(SEL)selector withObject:(id)sender
{
    [super performSelector:selector withObject:sender];
    //code...
}
```

Comment: I am interested in how to pass _CMD as selector rather than correct extraction for this specific code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have discovered your code doesn't call the superclass method as you want but the one in the current class, resulting in infinite recursion.

Your first option faced with this is to refactor your code, something along the lines of:

```
@implementation MyDerivedClass
{
   - (void)copy:(id)sender
   {
       [super copy:sender];
       [self commonCodeAfterSelector:_cmd withObject:sender];
   }

   - (void)cut:(id)sender
   {
       [super cut:sender];
       [self commonCodeAfterSelector:_cmd withObject:sender];
   }

   - (void)notifyAndPerformSelector:(SEL)selector withObject:(id)sender
   {
       //code...
   }
}
```

If this approach suits your situation use it. If not...

A second option is to become the compiler...

*Standard and super method calls*

A standard method call of the form:

```
[object someMethodWithArg1:x andArg2:y]
```

invokes a *search* for the method `someMethodWithArg1:andArg2:`. This search starts at the *runtime* class of `object`. The emphasis on *runtime* is important, the actual object referenced by `object` could be of the same class as the declared type of `object` *or* and of the subclasses of that type and the search must find the most derived implementation of the method.

A super method call of the form:

```
[super someMethodWithArg1:x andArg2:y]
```

also invokes a *search* for the method `someMethodWithArg1:andArg2:`. However in this search starts at the *compile time* class of *superclass* of the class in which code occurs. For example if `MyDerivedClass` above is a subclass of `MyBaseClass` then the search for the method starts at `MyBaseClass` *ignoring* the runtime type of `self` – which could be `MyDerivedClass` or a subclass of it (say `MyDerivedDerivedClass`)

*Why does your current code recurse?*

Your call:

```
[super performSelector:selector withObject:sender];
```

starts the search for the method `performSelector:withObject:` in the superclass, that search won't find the method until it reaches the `NSObject` class. Once found the method is invoked and starts a *standard* (not *super*) search for the method for `selector`, this search starts at the runtime type of `self` and so finds the method in `MyDerivedClass`... recursion.

What you need is something like:

```
[self performSuperSelector:selector withObject:sender];
```

but unfortunately that does not exist. But you can make one...

*Compiling method calls*

The compiler takes a standard method call of the form:

```
[object someMethodWithArg1:x andArg2:y]
```

and effectively (we're glossing over a few details, the need ones will get filled in below) compiles this to a call to the runtime function `objc_msgSend()`:

```
objc_msgSend(object, @selector("someMethodWithArg1:andArg2:"), x, y)
```

Notice that the selector is passed as a `SEL` value, this is where the value for `_cmd` comes from.

A super call of the form:

```
[super someMethodWithArg1:x andArg2:y]
```

is effectively compiled to a call to `objc_msgSendSuper()` of the form:

```
objc_msgSendSuper(`struct` containing `self` and superclass,
                  @selector("someMethodWithArg1:andArg2:"), x, y)
```

You can call these runtime functions directly in your own code. You must import the `<objc/objc-runtime.h>` to obtain the definitions, cast them to the appropriate type, etc.

*Becoming the compiler and bypassing `performSelector`*

Your code uses `performSelector` as it has a `SEL` value, but as shown above the runtime calls used for method calling take a `SEL` directly. If you "compile" the super call yourself you do not need to use `performSelector`, which in turn avoids the recursion problem.

Before calling `objc_msgSendSuper()` the function needs to be cast so its return and argument types match the actual return and argument types of the selector you are calling. This is so that the correct code is compiled to handle the arguments and return value, and that code is dependent on the types. The two selectors you are calling, `copy:` and `cut:`, have the same type which makes the code shorter. To make the casting easier we first define a shorthand for the type:

```
typedef void (*CutOrCopyRunner)(struct objc_super *super, SEL op, id sender);
```

which defines `CurOrCopyRunner` as a function pointer type. Now your method:

```
- (void)notifyAndPerformSelector:(SEL)selector withObject:(id)sender
{
   // "compile" [super selector:sender];

   // first cast objc_msgSendSuper to the correct type by
   // casting a function pointer to it (a function name by
   // itself, e.g. objc_msgSendSuper, evaluates to a pointer
   // to the function)
   CutOrCopyRunner msgSender = (CutOrCopyRunner)objc_msgSendSuper;

   // now build the first argument struct
   struct objc_super superInfo;
   superInfo.receiver = self;
   superInfo.super_class = MyDerivedClass.class.superclass;

   // now execute the super call
   msgSender(&superInfo, selector, sender);

   // code...
}
```

HTH